# E: Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate (Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: 17.04, libpng

When I run: `sudo apt-get install libpng12-0`, I get this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libpng12-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate
```

- How to fix this?
- Is having `libpng16-16` installed enough to do what `libpng12-0` does?

I have:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The repository in Ubuntu Zesty does not include `libpng12-0`. You have to download it from [Xenial's repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download). It will, in most cases, work smoothly.
2. `libpng16-16` has a seperate folder for its program `libpng16.so.16`, which is different from `libpng12-0` , which is `libpng12.so.0`, so having `libpng16-16` installed will not at all do what `libpng12-0 does`.